# Multiple datasets and sqlachemy and pytest

Tags: sqlalchemy, pytest, fixtures

So I have multiple test databases with the same tables and I need to run multiple tests for each of these databases in pytest.

What is the recommended way of going over it ?  The data is considerably big and I dont want to load the existing data every time for a test. So a fixture for the engine and seeding with data for each of these test databases will help. However I understand I cannot bind Base models with multiple engines. How can I have different instances of Base Models connected to different databases (or precached) and then based on the request , I bind to the database of interest ?